# Pushing an object in an array inside a loop

Tags: javascript, json

For few hours now I been trying to hack this but I really cant seem to succeed. I am trying to create a JSON string as below, but when passing the values of the variable `obj` to variable `j` I am getting an array of only the last result of that loop.

instead of getting results such as:

```
[{machine: "hi"...}
 {machine: "2"....}]
```

I am getting:

```
[{machine: "2"...}
 {machine: "2"....
 and keep going with same value}]
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
var return_json = function(){
    var j = [];
    var obj = {};
    var td;
    for(var i=1;i<tr.length;i++){
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
        obj['machine'] = td[0].innerHTML;
        console.log(obj['machine']);
        obj['day'] = td[1].getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML;
        obj['night'] = td[2].getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML;
        j.push(obj);
        console.log(j);
    }
    return j;
};

console.log(save_limitation());
```

Comment: Are you trying to create JSON string or iterate over a JSON obj?

Comment: @Alex I wish I could answer that but i dont know what i am doing. this is as far as I got.

Comment: If you want to create a `JSON` string, you can use `JSON.stringify()` and pass an array into it.

Comment: Define `var obj = {};` inside the `for` loop

Comment: @Satpal omg i spend so many hours trying to fix this, and all i had to do is degine var obj inside the loop ¬¬. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only creating a single object instance in `obj` variable before the loop. In every iteration, you update the properties of the object and push the same object into your array.

To fix it, create a new object within your loop at every iteration.

```
var return_json = function() {
    var j = [];
    var td;
    for(var i = 1; i < tr.length; i++){
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
        j.push({
            machine: td[0].innerHTML,
            day: td[1].getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML,
            night: td[2].getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML
        });
    }
    return j;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `obj` is defined outside of the loop you are adding *the same* object to the array each loop. You are updating the properties of `obj` on every iteration.
Define `obj` inside of the loop to ensure you are not doing this.

```js
var tr = document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName("tr");

var return_json = function(){
    var j = [];
    for(var i=1;i<tr.length;i++){
        var obj = {};
        var td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
        obj['machine'] = td[0].innerHTML;
        obj['day'] = td[1].getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML;
        obj['night'] = td[2].getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML;
        j.push(obj);
    }
    return j;
};

console.log(return_json());
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
<tr><td>Machine</td><td>Day</td><td>Night</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td><p>1d</p></td><td><p>1n</p></td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td><p>2d</p></td><td><p>2n</p></td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td><p>3d</p></td><td><p>3n</p></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try initalise the td and obj inside the loop for every element:

```
var return_json = function(){
        var j = [];
        for(var i=1;i<tr.length;i++){
        var obj = {};
        var td;
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
            obj['machine'] = td[0].innerHTML;
            console.log(obj['machine']);
            obj['day'] = td[1].getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML;
            obj['night'] = td[2].getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML;
            j.push(obj);
            console.log(j);
        }
        return j;
    };

    console.log(save_limitation());
```

Answer (score 0):

`obj.machine` is a reference to `td`. You need to remove the link to the `td` once it is assigned. This should solve it.

```
for(var i=1;i<tr.length;i++){
    td = {};
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    obj['machine'] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(td));
    console.log(obj['machine']);
    obj['day'] = td[1].getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML;
    obj['night'] = td[2].getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML;
    j.push(obj);
    console.log(j);
}
```